# Serial communication between Unity and arduino

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port

I am developing car racing game and I wanna to send current position of the car to arduino. but the car  stuck when serial.write(); included in c# script. How to fix it ?

Comment: Please provide more details: how do you send arduino commands via c#? Share some code or nobody can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have an Unity3D application with a car, and would like to send the position of the car to an Arduino via serial port.

There are several issues with the implementation of serial port in Unity 3D. For example it doesn't support the events associated with Serial (because Unity 3D is based on Mono which doesn't support them).

The other issue is that calling the serial functions in the Unity Update() will block or at least slow a lot the application.

Some users are using a backgroundworkerthread to read/write to the serial port without blocking the Update() loop of Unity.

Comment: That link appears to be stale or broken.